# How i can fix Cannot resolve keyword 'pub-date' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text

Tags: python, django

Python django

when I starting local sever,

I met only

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'pub-date' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
```

how can i fix?
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tIu0.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rxXU.png)

at first the problem was about direcotry, so read and search about django slash document.
and then i ment a new problem rn..

Comment: please share views.py file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You got this error because you have written `pub-date` instead of `pub_date` somewhere in your code.